# problems to see the items in the list with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a problem with the references in my custom array adapter.
I have an activity in which I use my array adapter in a layout in which I have defined several fields (including those I care now 2 buttons and a progress bar). When you press one button, it should display the progress bar, and pressing the other should hide it.

When I press the corresponding button, the progress bar is displayed with its row, but when I scroll on the list becomes visible to reuse the list.

Could you tell me how to make anything but display the progress of the row where I pressed? (Without displaying any another line)

this is my xml adapter (customadapterRutinalineadia)

this is my xml :

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLineasRutinaDiaEjercicioNoCompletado"
            android:layout_width="33sp"
            android:layout_height="27sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="NoK"
            android:textSize="6sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLineasRutinaDiaOk"
            android:layout_width="33sp"
            android:layout_height="27sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnLineasRutinaDiaEjercicioNoCompletado"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textSize="8sp" />



        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pgrLineasRutinaDiaProgreso"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chkLineasRutinaDiaHecho"
            android:visibility="invisible" />
```

Button `btnLineasRutinaDiaOk` is used to show the progress bar.
Button `btnLineasRutinaDiaEjercicioNoCompletado` is used to hide the progress bar.

This is my `ArrayAdapter`

```java
public class CustomAdapterRutinaDiaLineas extends ArrayAdapter<Rutina>{

 ArrayList<Rutina> lstRutinaDia;
 ArrayList<Rutina> arrayDatos;
 Rutina objRutina;
 static Context context;


    public CustomAdapterRutinaDiaLineas(Context contexto, ArrayList<Rutina> arrayDatos) {
       super(contexto, R.layout.ll_lineas_rutina_dia, arrayDatos);
       this.arrayDatos = arrayDatos;
       this.context = contexto;
    }

      @Override
    public View getView( int position,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        View vistaFila =null;

        final int ifila= position;
        //final View auxVistaFila=null;



        if (convertView == null) {
             //  LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();


            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            vistaFila = vi.inflate(R.layout.ll_lineas_rutina_dia, null);

            final View auxVistaFila = vistaFila;
          final ElementosLinea objelementos = new ElementosLinea();
           AsignarElementos(vistaFila,objelementos);


           objelementos.btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View re) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Rutina objru = (Rutina) objelementos.pgrProgresoCierre.getTag();


                AccesoBd objAcceso = new AccesoBd();
                objru._pgrProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //new CerrarEjercicio().execute("http://"+objAcceso.IpPc+"/CerrarEjercicioUnico.php");                  
                }
            });


         objelementos.btncerrar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Rutina objru = (Rutina) objelementos.pgrProgresoCierre.getTag();

                    AccesoBd objAcceso = new AccesoBd();
                    objru._pgrProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


            }
        });

         vistaFila.setTag(objelementos);
         objelementos.pgrProgresoCierre.setTag(arrayDatos.get(position));


       }else{
           vistaFila=convertView;
           ((ElementosLinea) vistaFila.getTag()).pgrProgresoCierre.setTag(arrayDatos.get(position));
       }


      Rutina datossss = arrayDatos.get(position);
      ElementosLinea objetos = (ElementosLinea)vistaFila.getTag();

           if (datossss.getProgreso()==null){

               datossss.setProgreso(objetos.pgrProgresoCierre);

            }

    return vistaFila;

    }

    private void AsignarElementos(View v,ElementosLinea Objetos){

         //cabeceras

          Objetos.btnOk=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnLineasRutinaDiaOk);

          Objetos.btncerrar=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnLineasRutinaDiaEjercicioNoCompletado);


          Objetos.pgrProgresoCierre=(ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.pgrLineasRutinaDiaProgreso);

    }
```

I just want to display the progressbar of only the item I clicked and none of the other items. is that the reason is to reutilzarse the list but can not find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understood your problem. You have a custom adapter. Each item within the adapter contains 2 buttons and a progress bar.  The buttons control their own respective progress bar's visibility.

My spanish is weak but I think I understood your code. Haven't tested this, but it should get you close.  You were storing something within the Progressbar's tag which I removed. Couldn't figure out what you were doing there but you can easily add that back in. It looks like you were trying to follow the ViewHolder paradigm but messed up a little. Hopefully the below code will get you on track.

Also, storing the ArrayAdapters context in a static global field is not a good idea. The ArrayAdapter already has the method getContext() to use within the Adapter itself. Otherwise you shouldn't have a need to access it's context externally.

**Update**: Oh I see, you want to track the Adapter's item's position as well. No need to store that within the ProgressBar's tag. Modified sample code to account for that.

**Update**: Reformed code to function properly.

```java
public class CustomAdapterRutinaDiaLineas extends ArrayAdapter<Rutina> {

ArrayList<Rutina> lstRutinaDia;
ArrayList<Rutina> arrayDatos;
Rutina            objRutina;

public CustomAdapterRutinaDiaLineas(Context contexto, ArrayList<Rutina> arrayDatos) {
    super(contexto, R.layout.ll_lineas_rutina_dia, arrayDatos);
    this.arrayDatos = arrayDatos;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vistaFila = null;
    ViewHolder vh;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        vistaFila = vi.inflate(R.layout.ll_lineas_rutina_dia, null);
        vh = new ViewHolder();

        vh.position = position;
        vh.btnOk = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLineasRutinaDiaOk);
        vh.btncerrar = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLineasRutinaDiaEjercicioNoCompletado);
        vh.pgrProgresoCierre = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pgrLineasRutinaDiaProgreso);
        vh.btnOk.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ProgressBar)v.getTag()).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        vh.btncerrar.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((ProgressBar)v.getTag()).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
        vh.btncerrar.setTag(vh.pgrProgresoCierre);
        vh.btnOk.setTag(vh.pgrProgresoCierre);

        vistaFila.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vistaFila = convertView;
        vh = (ViewHolder) vistaFila.getTag();
        vh.position = position;
    }

    Rutina datossss = arrayDatos.get(position);
    if (datossss.getProgreso() == null) {
        datossss.setProgreso(vh.pgrProgresoCierre);
    }

    return vistaFila;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    int position;
    Button btnOk;
    Button btnCerrar;
    ProgressBar pgrProgresoCierre;
}
}
```

Comment: my view lists holder so called asigo elements in asignarelementos ()
tells me that the object has to be final objelementos

Comment: Oh right, that's because of the anonymous inner class.  Will update my code. Just make vh final. I would do away with your asignarelementos() method.

Comment: I tell him that if you check in the desired position, but when you scrool it gives me the progressbar visible in another row which is where you press

Comment: No entiendo su inglés. Por favor podría decir en español?

Comment: el problema lo tengo al reutilizar las listas, si por ejemplo hago cilck en el boton de la posicion 0 (pongamos que mi lista tiene 15 elementos y se ven 4 a la vez) pues el 5 tambien se pones visible y el 10 es decir el primer elemento cuando hago el scroll, (es decir cuando hago click lo hace bien solo que me reutiliza la vista, me gustaria sabaer en que posicion estoy cuando hago click)

Comment: Ok I think I'm tracking more. The convertView (vistaFila) is reused as you scroll. As a result, you MUST always update the information each list item should display with every getView() call. In your case, you must always update the position. Good luck!

Comment: el problema sigue siendo el mismo, al hacer clik sobre el boton se sigue mostrando el progres en otras lineas que no le corresponden

Comment: as usual keeps repeating , ¿know any example?

Comment: Made some changes to the code above. Try that. Gets rid of that final ViewHolder issue. I tested a similar code and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't assessed your code closely, but I think I know what's happening. Here's my idea:

This is because your views are being recycled, so anything you do in getView() can be undone when that row is inflated again.

Because of this, you should rather have an `ArrayList` or `Array` of some sort in your CustomAdapter that can have a list of boolean values (this will get more complex as you want to get more things to save).

Then, when you do click on the button, simply set the corresponding value in the array to be `true`.

For example, let's say you have 10 rows, and none of the progress bars should be shown yet. Your array looks like this:

> [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false
>   ]

Let's say the button is clicked on row 2 (array position 1). Then, show the bar and set the array value to true:

> [false, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false ]

Now, in the `getView()`, whenever you inflate your row layout, you can check the array, observe if it's true or false, and set the progress bar to `hidden/not hidden` accordingly.

If I'm off on this, I apologize, but I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not able to show the position in which I find myself